# What is the Raspberry Pi key for on the PI 400?

Tags: keyboard

I have a new Raspberry PI 400. What is the 'Raspberry Pi key' for? - between 'Fn and 'Alt' -. I cannot find it anywhere on the web.

Comment: I would guess it is the "windows", aka. "super" key which most modern pc keyboards have; it is usually the 4 square flag icon from MS Windows.  It may or may not do anything all by itself by default in the RpiOS GUI.  I use it as a modifier key for custom shortcuts, since many/most 'Alt' and 'Ctrl' (with which it can be combined) combination (Alt-x, Alt-F1, etc) are often taken by an application or the desktop environment.

Answer (score 4):

It's the "super key" or Windows key. As far as I'm away it's only purpose in the Raspberry Pi OS is to open the main menu (which also has a Raspberry Pi logo) which you can then navigate using the arrow keys which is handy if you don't have a mouse.

On Ubuntu, there are key combinations for e.g. Super key + 1 which opens the first application in the dock.

Comment: You can probably use it in custom shortcuts in the GUI.